# Download a file and scroll to bottom div on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

On link click, I want the user to download a file (in the href). On that same click, at the same time, I want to scroll them down the page to a form.

Based on my code, I can only do one or the other. I'm unable to perform both actions.

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/images/dog2.jpg" download="dog2.jpg"
    class="scroll-to-bottom-link">Scroll to bottom</a>
<p>here is some secondary information</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.scroll-to-bottom-link').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop : $('body').height() }, 800);
return false;
});
```

Any ideas on how to do this? Other options I've found use `href="#"`, but I need that for my download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put a `div` in the `a` tag and attach the event to it

```
   <a href="http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/images/dog2.jpg" download ><div class="scroll-to-bottom-link">Scroll to bottom</div></a>
    <p>here is some secondary information</p>
```

and then remove the `remove false` from the function.

```
$('.scroll-to-bottom-link').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : $('body').height() }, 800);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w61oteod/3/)

Comment: i'd love too, unfortunately it says i don't have enough reputation. i'm a newbie so sorry if i'm doing something wrong here. i do appreciate the help tho @francesco-e

Answer (score 1):

You must remove a `return false`, because it calls a [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), which blocks a download.

It will be enough:

```
$('.scroll-to-bottom-link').click(function(){
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : $('body').height() }, 800);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w61oteod/2)

Comment: Thanks for the help! This solves exactly my issues. I really appreciate your help.